# Filter features from a DLL project while compiling VisualStudio solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, compilation, conditional-compilation

My working context is that I have two solutions in Visual Studio. Each of these solutions will build a different application. Each of them has the startup project, that is the UI for each of them and both solutions are using the same project (from other repository) as a base structure for the functionality.

Then each solution consists on a UI project, and one non-UI project which builds a DLL.

As the applications are different (each one is for a different customer) and each one of them will have some features enabled, but not all of them, and I don't want to compile the non UI DLL with all the code, I need to be able to compile the solutions with only the needed code for each application.

To be more precise, imagine that the base project (the DLL) has three features: A, B and C
I want to be able to configure the solution, so the UI project 1 only compiles the DLL with features A and B, while the UI project 2 only compiles the DLL with feature C enabled.

Could you point me on the right direction to achieve this?

Thanks in advance to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this.

> The #if directive, with the #elif, #else, and #endif directives, controls compilation of portions of a source file. If the expression you write (after the >#if) has a nonzero value, the line group immediately following the #if directive >is retained in the translation unit

from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en->us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx)

```
#if defined(FEATUREONE)  
    feature1();  
#elif defined(FEATURETWO)  
    feature2();  
#else  
    Default();  
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks Pribina
That's my current solution, but I'm trying to find different options, so the solution could be more scalable.
If in a future we have more than two different UI, using  these directives won't be too much clean

Comment: i dig into it little bit and i found one codeproject https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/451734/Visual-Studio-Use-Conditional-Compilation-to-Contr

Comment: Thanks again Pribina.
I'm not totally sure if that would work for me.
My main concercn is having a UI which creates these conditional compilation symbols, and depending on them, the project which generates the DLL compiles a part of the code or the whole code
But what I need is that the DLL project doesn't need to know anything from the UI

Comment: Can you provide some example of UI ? what UI are you using WebForms? MVC?

Comment: I'm working with WPF, so I have a project with the main window and it instantiates the base project, which compiles the DLL
What I need is that depending on the configuration in the main Window, the compilation on the DLL is different